how do I quantify likelihood of bad data - Bayes / Posterior distribution
Problem: I have a ratio statistic and I want to separate out bad data and flag accounts that have unreliable data for a particular feature of a predictive model.

The ratio is # events per 1000 mile
The mean is low
Goal is to identify some threshold that helps identify that the likelihood of observations is less than some threshold (.025, .05)
Challenge is there is quite a bit of variance in the observed ratios by customer.  Also the number of miles (observations) varies significantly as well.


There isn't enough information to answer this.  More to the point, even if you have a specified model, how you chose to treat outliers is very subjective.  There is no absolute mathematic answer.  Outliers occur, even without "bad" data.
